# Why doesn't my selection sort code work when there are duplicate numbers?

Tags: javascript, selection-sort

I've tested my code with arrays that have non-duplicate values, and it seems to work fine. When I do have duplicates, it doesn't work.

This is what I have so far. I think the line of code where I find the minimum value of the sliced array is giving me problems.

```js
function selectionSort(array) {
 
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        let min = Math.min(...array.slice(i));
        let indexMin = array.indexOf(min)
        array.splice(indexMin, 1)
        array.splice(i,0,min);
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(selectionSort([3, 0, -5, -5]));
```

With a test array of [3,0,-5,-5], in the first iteration of the loop, the min is -5 and the indexMin is 2. After I splice the array, I get [3,0,-5]. When I splice it again (to insert the value at the beginning of the array) I get [-5,3,0,-5] as expected. In the second iteration, I would expect the min to be the -5 at index 3... but when I console.log the min, it says it's the -5 at index 0. I specified that I want to find the min from (...array.slice(1)), so why is it setting min to -5 at index 0?

Comment: "*I specified that I want to find the min from (...array.slice(1))*" - Yes, but you also specified that you want to find the index of that element in the whole array: `array.indexOf(min)` (including the already sorted part).

Comment: `indexOf` also takes a `fromIndex` as the second parameter - try `array.indexOf(min, i)`

Comment: You should not use `splice`, you should simply swap the two elements. An array is not a list, the `splice` operation is not cheap (although it hardly matters for complexity, selection sort is `O(n²)` anyway)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you have duplicates `indexOf` returns the index of the first one, which is not what you want once you are done with it after you've seen it once —– it always finds the first occurrence even when there are multiple.

`indexOf()` takes an optional second parameter to indicate where to start the search. You can pass in `i` to start at the correct spot skipping over the already sorted values.

```js
function selectionSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let min = Math.min(...array.slice(i));
    let indexMin = array.indexOf(min, i); // pass in i
    [array[indexMin], array[i]] = [array[i], array[indexMin]]
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(selectionSort([4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1]))
```

Comment: `lastIndexOf` would give the index of the last matching element in the array - `indexOf(min, i)` is what's needed here

Comment: You can replace the two splices with `[array[i], array[indexMin]] = [array[indexMin], array[i]];` assuming you end the previous line with a semicolon (which you currently don't).

Comment: I agree @PatrickRoberts, was just thinking about the immediate problem. But there's no sense having the `splice`s.